# Do bloodragers have to be "Barbarians"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

I know this seems a stupid question, but I mean it as this

> ### Barbarian |bärˈbe(ə)rēən|
>
> noun
> (in ancient times) a member of a community or tribe not belonging to one of the great civilizations (Greek, Roman, Christian).
>
> - **an uncultured or brutish person.**

I basically mean, does a bloodrager have to be a primitive brute who only knows kill? or can they be civilized and refined?

Comment: [Highly useful answer on this topic](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/50450/15469).

Answer (score 5):

Mechanically speaking there is nothing forcing them into that sort of personality.  Though by the ability scores chosen by those who play it and the ability score focus of the class it's likely to be rather common.  Roleplaying your ability scores well should be a priority, so if you have a low Intelligence and a low Wisdom there's a good chance you're not going to be very smart.  Even then though there isn't anything stopping you from being "cultured" really, but it would be a bit harder to roleplay accurately given such scores.

Comment: I like this, I understand that, and as I've build him, he's quite intelligent, but not wise. I was nervous that, whilst the class doesn't make him stupid, that learning rage of any kind pigeon-holes him into that he was of a primitive tribe

Comment: You could always play him along the way of a Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde type of situation.  I mean more along the lines of how Mr. Hyde acted in general though, considering he was a pretty posh character when he wasn't incredibly pissed and/or ripping people apart.

Comment: "Posh" isn't the word, but that's pretty accurate. Just that he's gotten education from the royal academy; he's learned battle from a friend of his grandfather's as a mentor, and he was a smith's student from his father